# Who am I? I'm found in all angels, and core of the Devil

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'm found in all angels, and core of the Devil,
My forebears once dined 'cross the ol' English channel.
If fish is your wish, I can help fill your dish,
I go well with pie and with freshly cut sandwich.

I wax and I wane with the tick of the hour,
I only submit to my half-lunar ruler.
Don't argue with me, though the night may be long-
Though sometimes I'm right, I will never be wrong.

**Who am I?**

Comment: My guess is there's a lot of wordplay here...

Comment: There is some but perhaps not as much as you think.

Comment: Across the English Channel from which side...?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're

> an Angle

I'm found in all angels, and core of the Devil,

> Angel is an anagram, while the "core" of Devil is **V**, which is simply an angle.

My forebears once dined 'cross the ol' English channel.

> [Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles), I assume

If fish is your wish, I can help fill your dish,

> Anglers catch fish

I go well with pie and with freshly cut sandwich.

> Cutting pies or sandwiches creates a wedge (angle) shape. Could also be a play on pi.

I wax and I wane with the tick of the hour,

> The angles between hands on a clock

I only submit to my half-lunar ruler.

> Maybe it's referring to a half-moon shaped protractor, not sure. (confirmed by OP in comments)

Don't argue with me, though the night may be long-

> Some angles are *obtuse*, or "annoyingly insensitive or slow to understand".

Though sometimes I'm right, I will never be wrong.

> There are *right* angles, but I've never heard of a *wrong* one.

Comment: You're good at solving my riddles aren't you?

Comment: Two out of three ain't bad. Ask some more :D

Comment: BTW half-lunar ruler is correct.  A protractor looks a lot like a ruler for measuring angles not distances.

Comment: The key for me on this one was the last line. When thinking of things described as "right", my mind goes to angles/triangles. From there it was just singling out each reference.